# Picard iteration for second order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Any help for the following two questions will be much appreciated:

Question 1:

Consder the ODE with IVP

$y''(t)+g(t,y)=0, \ y(0)=y_0,\ y'(0)=z_0$

where g is continues on some region $D$, $(0,y_0)\in D$. I want to show that this is equivalent to the integral equation

$ \begin{align}
y(t)=y_0+z_0t-\int_0^t (t-s)g(s,y(s))ds 
\end{align}
\\
$

This is what I have done so far to solve this: I integra either side and get

$ \int_0^t y''(s) ds =-\int_0^t g(s,f(s)) ds$ I calculate this, integrate again and get

$y(s)=y_0+z_0t-\int_0^t \int_0^t g(s,f(s))ds$. My problem is that I don't know what to do with this last double integral.

Question 2:

Consider the same integral equation where $g(y,t)$, $\frac{\partial g}{ \partial y} (t,y)$ are continuous on the rectangle $D=\{ (t,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \mid t \mid \leq a, \mid y-y_0 \mid \leq b\}$. Let $\mid g(t,y) \mid \leq M$, $\mid \frac{\partial g}{ \partial y}  (t,y) \mid \leq K$ for all $(t,y) \in D$. We define $\phi_0(t)=y_0$ and

$
\phi_n(t)=y_0+z_0t-\int_0^t (t-s)g(s,y(s))ds 
$

I want to show that $\phi_n(t)$ is well defiend for $\mid t\mid \leq \min \{a,\frac{2b}{2\mid z_0\mid+2M}\}$. Here I am quite lost. To show it is well-defined I need to show that the integral is never infinity. But I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: How come you have not got an answer yet!

Comment: I don't know, hopefully some kind soul will come by soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try showing $r_j(t)=|\phi_{j+1}(t)-\phi_j(t)| \leq \frac{M(|z_0|+\frac{Ma}{2})K^{j}t^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$.

If K<1, then $r_j(t) \leq \frac{M(|z_0|+\frac{Ma}{2})t^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$
If K>1, then $r_j(t) \leq \frac{M(|z_0|+\frac{Ma}{2})K^{2j+1}t^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$ which are the terms of hyperbolic sin function, which converges.